# expect(service).toBeDefined throws error in Angular JS - TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am new to Angular JS and trying to write a unit test for my service in mocha, but getting below error everytime it is run. Please suggest.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'expect(InfoService).toBeDefined()')
```

Unit test :

```
describe('Unit: InfoService', function () {

    var InfoService;
    var httpMock;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app.Info'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('CONSTANT', {
        DETAIL_URL:'/test/someurl/'
    });          
}));

beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend,InfoService) {
    InfoService = InfoService;
        httpMock = $httpBackend;
    }));

    it('InfoService should exist', function(InfoService){
        expect(InfoService).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Comment: Check the version of jasmine you are using has `toBeDefined`. Also you have local variable and and global variable having the same name for `InfoService`.

Comment: I am using "karma-jasmine": "0.1.5" and also even if i change the variable name, i am getting the error

Comment: variable name was a different thing. The version of jasmine you are using is very very old and might not have toBeDefined function

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed to latest version and still facing the issue.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am encountering the same problem. Cheers.